# If there exists a complex root $\alpha$ of $ f(x)$ with multiplicity > 1,then $f(f(x)) $ also has a complex root with multiplicity > 1for polynomial f

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, continuity, roots

Let $f(x)$ be a nonconstant polynomial with real coefficients. If there exists a complex root $\alpha$ of $ f(x)$ with multiplicity greater than 1, then prove that $f(f(x)) $ also has a complex root with multiplicity greater than 1.

My attempt was to consider $f(x)$ as $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^d p(x)$ where $d>1$ and $p(\alpha)\neq0$. But after evaluating $f(f(x))$ it becomes much more complicated and very uneasy to prove the result.

Comment: What becomes complicated? $f(f(x))=(f(x)-a)^dp(f(x))$ - now where in that expression are you looking to find a multiple root?

Comment: Okay , Now should I say $f(x)=a$ ,d times, must have a complex root say $\beta$ as $\mathbb C$ is algebrically closed . Therefore $\beta$ is a multiple root of $f(f(x))$